# angular2 template not change whatever i do

Tags: angular

Im trying to make my very first steps on Angular2, 
I had a bug and I fixed it, but right now, my decorator template does taking any effect:

```
  /// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import { Component } from '@angular2/core';
import {MessageComponent } from "./messages/message.component";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` 
        <div class="row" >
             <section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message.content">
             </section >
        </div >
        <div class="row" >
            <section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >

               <my-message ></my-message>

            </section >

        </div >

    `,
    directives:[MessageComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {


}
```

right now, I'm seeing the input typed text, but even if I'm doing something like that :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` 

    `,
    directives:[MessageComponent]
})
```

I still seeing the input typed text I just erased. which is weird..

I tried to change anything, add h1 tag in the template, even delete everything in the template , but it keeps showing me my old code. (input typed text on the screen). nothing changes.

I've got no errors or whatsoever.

Comment: After erasing and adding content(h1) do you save file?

Comment: yeah sure.
also tried to delete cache from my browser.. but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Input from '@angular/core' in your message component and then define it in your message component class like:

```
@Input() message: string;
```

in your app template you should pass the message to the child component like this:

```
<my-message [message]="message.content"></my-message>
```

Comment: I don't think its related to my question: I asked why angular template doesn't taking any changes (even if I delete any of my html code, I still can see the old html code..)

Comment: Your html is not updating because you never tell it to update... You have an input where you write your message but you do not pass it in any way to any other component. I shown you the way to achieve updating values in your html document through binding your input to your child component :-)

Comment: ok. tried what you said ..still nothing changes..  :(
just to let you know what the problem is : even if i delete everything (including the "my-message" tag) and including everything, it stills showing the input text (even if i delte the input text itself..)

Comment: can you paste the rest of your code so I can get the bigger picture ? and also what angular 2 version do you use ?

Comment: and I'm using angular 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Then I think you should move to a new version if you are just starting, the final 2.0 version has been released a couple of days ago. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123635/discussion-between-matwaligora-and-thormayer).